# Debugging Bash Script: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, shell, getopt

Tried debugging this one a few different ways and bash -x and setting display lines was no help. I screened it for non-ascii chars and still no dice.
Went through and checked for logical errors and didn't see anything that unterminated or inf loops. I am thinking my getopt syntax is to blame but I followed the guidlines in manpage and couldn't find any issues.

It's a decently long setup script but so I hosted it here:
[cdr.sh - deployment script](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/581149/cdr.sh)

Comment: Post the code into the question. Not following _blind links_

Comment: Syntax errors can be debugged without executing the script, using the `-n` switch. Cut your program down into smaller pieces until the error becomes obvious.

Comment: From experimenting, it seems to be the lack of whitespace between the closing brace for `set_remotedb_configs` and the following comment

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: Try the following site :- http://www.shellcheck.net/ .... or you can install shellcheck and use on your system

Comment: Replace `}#` by `} #`.

Comment: @Cyrus think you spotted it on Line 142.

Answer (score 2):

@cyrus spotted it.
The # without space next to closing brace on that function, thanks!
I'm surprised spellcheck didn't find that one and I guess i should change my synax colors in vim because the functions were same blue as comments.

Comment: My syntax checker did not spot it either, but the error told you 'syntax error'. That means it is time to check brackets. Pretty nasty one to discover in a bigger script, had it once before but I had two functions so - oh well! cheers.